# Unable to install asp.net 5 on Mac OS X

Tags: asp.net, macos

I'm having trouble installing asp.net 5 on OS X. I've followed the instructions found [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html).

After running the first command on terminal;

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source ~/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
```

I get this result;

```
Downloading dnvm as script to '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/mo/.dnx/dnvm'

grep: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
grep: HD/Users/mo/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
Appending source string to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/mo/.bash_profile
Type 'source /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/mo/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh' to start using dnvm
-bash: HD/Users/mo/.dnx:/usr/local/lib/dnx: No such file or directory
```

I'm assuming this is an issue due to the space in the file path. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bug in their installation script that doesn't escape spaces in your file path. Try Renaming your Hard Disk to something without spaces such as "MacHD" and then running the install again.

Comment: Renaming the HDD seems kind of drastic. Would probably be easier to submit a patch for the scripts.

Comment: I agree with @mason renaming the HDD is drastic. Macintosh HD is the default name so I would assume others have had this issue and have resolved it without having to rename it

Comment: IF you just need to install, you might rename your HD and then rename it back once the install is complete.